# How to delete orphaned child rows in Postgres database?

Tags: database, postgresql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have a Postgres database with orphaned child rows in some tables. (No parent table rows for child table).

I wonder how it is possible in Database tables. My questions are,

1. How this situation occurs in database? Any best practices for avoiding this?
2. How to delete only orphaned child rows?

Comment: 1) (FK)  constraints 2) `delete ftom t where not exists( select ... from p where ...)`

Comment: Apparently you have not defined foreign keys in your database, otherwise this wouldn't be possible.